# Difference in difference, same introduction time but different duration

Tags: r

I am looking at a case where you take a 2-year degree. I do not have panel data, each person is observed once. I have cohorts for the years 2013-2019.

I have two groups. A control group and a treatment group (persons subject to reform). In 2019, there was a reform. Which means that the treatment group in the 2018 cohort was affected 1 out of 2 study years and the 2019 cohort 2 out of 2 study years.

I want to estimate the effect of being in the treatment group, but take into account that some were partially treated and others fully treated. I was thinking of

```r
y = treated + cohort2018Xtreated + cohort2019Xtreated + cohort fixed effect + studyfixedeffect + X + e
```

The parallel trend assumption will then be broken when the partly treated cohort from 2018 is used to estimate the effect for the 2019 cohort?

How can I estimate this?